# .NET Core Web API and Postgres DB Connection String

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am starting a web api which uses postgres as the backend.

I am on a team of developers that will each have a local db for development. How can I ensure that if a new developer comes on the team that their local db is created without manually creating it themself.

As of right now, we each created our local db's through command line and update our appsettings.Development.json to use our local db connection string (which is on the gitignore incase we use sensitive passwords).

It's annoying to have to manually set this portion up however. Is there anyway to just have a database be created on the fly? As in, right when they launch the API, the db should be created and the migrations applied onto it.

appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Local": "Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=mydb;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;"
  }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    UpdateDatabase(app);
    
    // Other configurations
}

public virtual void UpdateDatabase(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    using var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices
        .GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>()
        .CreateScope();

    using var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MyDbContext>();

    context.Database.EnsureCreated();

    context.Database.Migrate();
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand the question, It seems you are using migrations in your project. They should allow you apply the scripts (or other code) upgrading each of your local DBs.

Comment: It was a while back but I guess the question is more about how can I have a localdb auto spin up and have everyone have the same db connection (it is for dev so it's not like the password is needed to be that secure). It would just save time instead of everyone having to create a database initially.